# Which version control suits best this list of requirements

Tags: windows, version-control

Our dev team is small (3 developers) and windows based.
I'm looking for a source control that can do the following:

Check out files for editing and warn others that file is used
Check in files and merge if they have changed 
Split baselines for release versions and merge baselines if needed 
Visual Studio integration 
Can work over WAN

Thanks.
SW

Comment: i am not sure that having to warn users that a file is checked out for editing by someone else is that big of a deal if you have a good merge tool support. Most of the popular OSS are "concurrent" version control systems which means no locking.

Comment: I kind of agree, but I guess it depends on the team. The arguments against locking are sensible, but still there's something nice and comforting about knowing when you commit a file, it is exactly as you made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Server fits all of those.

Comment: TFS is a bit spendy for 3 devs (in terms of setup/maintenance time *and* cost).

Comment: Agreed. I can't think of another system that lets you see who else has the file checked out, however. I don't think this feature is probably as necessary for only 3 devs though, between locks, merges, and just asking the other 2 guys what they're working on you should be covered.

Answer (score 1):

SVN would be great, as long as you use locking (normally the server has no idea what clients are doing by default)

Perforce might be a nice one to look at which does this more by default.

Both have VS integration, SVN especially.

Answer (score 1):

SVN, provided that you explicitly lock the files.  This is not by default, but you can easily lock the file via SVN commands or via TortoiseSVN.

VisualSVN provides the Visual Studio integration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want good Visual Studio Integration, then check out [Microsoft Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx). You didn't specify if you wanted free or commercial or how critical Visual Studio intergration was.

Answer (score 0):

git will do almost all of it.  Not sure about integrating it with Visual Studio though.  there might be a plugin for that.
Reasons:

- No central server needed.  If you want one, you can have one, but it's not necessary
- You can push/pull changes to the others at will.
- Each of you can have your own local branches, and push only the ones you need to
  each other.  Branching/merging is easy enough to do branch-per-task.  Then push just that task to a co-worker if needed.
- Unlike SVN, only one directory is needed for git, in the top level of the directory structure.
- git stash rocks for when you have changes in your current branch, and need to switch to another for a while.  This is one of those things you don't miss until you don't have.
- Merges are awesome.

Comment: So why suggest it? Just to evangelise?

Comment: Visual studio is listed as supported at wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software#User_interfaces) and 
http://swik.net/VisualStudio+git have some links with positive user experiences.

Comment: @john.  several reasons.  1) It's 90% there, and has great command line support.  2) I don't deal with MS products, and so would have no reason to know 3) I'm not all knowing.

Comment: But since other well known and more established tools exist, what's the advantage of GIT in this case?